# Deployed contract has NO bytecode

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask, remix

I am testing a smart contract on the Sepolia network. It works as planned when I deploy it with Remix through MetaMask. But when I try to do so with web3js on localhost through MetaMask, providing the exact same bytecode, the deployed contract turns out empty... Without raising ANY errors whatsoever...
That recently changed though, since it now fails the transaction with the following message: `Error deploying contract: Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit.`

This does not make sense at all though, since it deploys perfectly on Remix. I've even tried to use the copy-pasted bytecode from its compiler, but it's the exact same as the one compiled with Brownie.

It must be something related to the optimization runs. Without setting the number of runs explicitly to 100 or 150, the contract turns out too big.

The following is my client code used for deployment on localhost:

```
async function deployNewIdea(abi, bytecode) {
  // Address of the original Idea contract
  const web3 = getWeb3Provider();

    try {

    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts().catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
    const Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
    const deploy = Contract.deploy({
      data: bytecode,
      from: accounts[0]
    });
 
    const gasEstimate = await deploy.estimateGas();
    
    const parameters = {
      gas: gasEstimate,
      from: accounts[0]
    };

    const deployedContract = await deploy.send(parameters, (err, transactionHash) => {
    console.log('Transaction Hash :', transactionHash);
}).on('confirmation', () => {}).then((newContractInstance) => {
    return newContractInstance;
});

var web3Provider = undefined;
function getWeb3Provider() {
    if (!web3Provider) {
        web3Provider = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    }
    return web3Provider;
}
```

I would like for it to act the exact same way as Remix. But it doesn't. Am I doing something completely wrong? If so, what?

Answer (score 0):

I WAS setting the gas limit to a value that was too small...

The gas estimate (`const gasEstimate = await deploy.estimateGas();`) was giving me a value that was a tiny bit below the acutal required gas limit.

So, I tried to deploy it with a constant amount of `9 000 000 gas` (the previous gas estimate was `5 716 054 gas`) and the deploy went through. Filled with code!

Now, I still wanted to make use of the gas estimate, since I didn't want to set the gas limit to an unnecessarily high value. So, I checked how much gas that was actually used for the transaction (`6 166 253 gas`). Took that value and subtracted the original estimate from it; `6 166 253 gas - 5 716 054 gas = 450 199 gas`. Then  I added that value to the gas estimation; `const gasEstimate = await deploy.estimateGas() + 450199;`.

And it worked. Might only work for one specific deploy, since the error/deviation might be proportional to the amount of gas used in a transaction. Here is the new code, anyway:

```
async function deployNewIdea(abi, bytecode) {
  // Address of the original Idea contract
  const web3 = getWeb3Provider();

    try {

    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts().catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
    const Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
    const deploy = Contract.deploy({
      data: bytecode,
      from: accounts[0]
    });
 
    const gasEstimate = await deploy.estimateGas() + 450199;
    
    const parameters = {
      gas: gasEstimate,
      from: accounts[0]
    };

    const deployedContract = await deploy.send(parameters, (err, transactionHash) => {
    console.log('Transaction Hash :', transactionHash);
}).on('confirmation', () => {}).then((newContractInstance) => {
    return newContractInstance;
});

var web3Provider = undefined;
function getWeb3Provider() {
    if (!web3Provider) {
        web3Provider = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    }
    return web3Provider;
}
```